# searching an array of objects on the basis of value present inside an value of an object in form of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array-filter, arrayofarrays

I have an an object with two fields `filter1` and `filter2` having values in form of array

`let filter = {filter1:["mine","your"]: filter2:["C","D"]}`  //values not fixed

the data is in form of array of objects

```
let data = [
{ id:1, filter1:["mine"], filter2:["E","C"]},
{ id:2, filter1:["mine"], filter2:["E","C","F"]},
{ id:3, filter1:["your"], filter2:["C"]},
{ id:3, filter1:["your"], filter2:["D","C"]},
{ id:5, filter1:["other"], filter2:["F"]},
...
]
```

I have to filter out those objects which have any one of the fields present in specific key
for eg if `filter` is `{filter1:["mine"]: filter2:["F","D"]}` it will first search for any element of filter1 in filter1 of data object and after that search for any element of filter2 which is present in the filter2 of data object and return the object if any one them is found

`few example`

result for   `{filter1:["mine"]: filter2:["F","D"]}`

```
result = [
{ id:1, filter1:["mine"], filter2:["E","C"]}, //since filter1 "mine"
{ id:2, filter1:["mine"], filter2:["E","C","F"]}, //since filter1 "mine"
{ id:3, filter1:["your"], filter2:["D","C"]}, //since from "F" and "D" from filter2 "D" is present
{ id:5, filter1:["other"], filter2:["F"]}, //since "F" from filter2 is present
]
```

result for   `{filter1:["your"]: filter2:["F","G"]}`

```
result = [
{ id:2, filter1:["mine"], filter2:["E","C","F"]}, //since "F" from filter2 is present
{ id:3, filter1:["your"], filter2:["D","C"]}, //since filter1 is "your"
{ id:5, filter1:["other"], filter2:["F"]}, //since "F" from filter2 is present
]
```

result for   `{filter1:[]: filter2:["D"]}`

```
result = [
{ id:3, filter1:["your"], filter2:["D","C"]}, //since filter2 has "D"
]
```

Comment: You could use Array.prototype.filter().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const data = [
  { id:1, filter1:["mine"], filter2:["E","C"]},
  { id:2, filter1:["mine"], filter2:["E","C","F"]},
  { id:3, filter1:["your"], filter2:["C"]},
  { id:3, filter1:["your"], filter2:["D","C"]},
  { id:5, filter1:["other"], filter2:["F"]}
];

const search = ({ filter1, filter2 }) => 
  data.filter(item => 
    item.filter1.some(fItem => filter1.includes(fItem)) ||
    item.filter2.some(fItem => filter2.includes(fItem))
);

const result = search({ filter1:["mine"], filter2:["F","D"] });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: if the filter1 is not in the form of array like this const data = [
  { id:1, filter1:"mine", filter2:["E","C"]},
  { id:2, filter1:"mine", filter2:["E","C","F"]},
]; then the use of some will throw the error how to handle that

Comment: See the use of `concat()` in my answer to address this.

Comment: Yes, @pilchard is correct. Replace `item.filter1.some` with `[].concat(item.filter1).some`, and do the same for the next line. Then it will handle data that contains strings instead of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize the [solution proposed by RoMilton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69701184/13762301) by calling `some()` on the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the passed filter object, and then iterating each `key` and `filter_array` with nested `some()` calls.

If you also [`Array#concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the currently iterated data element property into an array you can include non-array properties in the filter object ie `id` in this case.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, filter1: ["mine"], filter2: ["E", "C"] },
  { id: 2, filter1: ["mine"], filter2: ["E", "C", "F"] },
  { id: 3, filter1: ["your"], filter2: ["C"] },
  { id: 3, filter1: ["your"], filter2: ["D", "C"] },
  { id: 5, filter1: ["other"], filter2: ["F"] }
];

const search = (array, filter_object) =>
  array.filter(item =>
    Object.entries(filter_object).some(([key, filter_array]) =>
      [].concat(item[key]).some(fitem => filter_array.includes(fitem)))
  );

const filter = { filter1: ["mine"], filter2: ["F", "D"] };
const result = search(data, filter);

console.log(...result.map(({ id }) => ({ id })));

const filter2 = { id: [5], filter1: ["mine"] }
const result2 = search(data, filter2);

console.log(...result2.map(({ id }) => ({ id })));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This use of `concat()` can also be applied to the hard coded solution to allow for properties that may not be arrays in your data array.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, filter1: "mine", filter2: ["E", "C"] },
  { id: 2, filter1: ["mine"], filter2: ["E", "C", "F"] },
  { id: 3, filter1: ["your"], filter2: ["C"] },
  { id: 3, filter1: ["your"], filter2: ["D", "C"] },
  { id: 5, filter1: ["other"], filter2: ["F"] }
];

const search = ({ filter1, filter2 }) => (
  data.filter(item =>
    [].concat(item.filter1).some(fItem => filter1.includes(fItem)) ||
    [].concat(item.filter2).some(fItem => filter2.includes(fItem))
  ));

const result = search({ filter1: ["mine"], filter2: ["F", "D"] });
console.log(result);
```